# ¿Cómo crear una función en la que 10 números (definidos por el usuario) se vayan sumando cada dos?

Tags: javascript, array, function

Tengo el siguiente problema que resolver: **"Crear una función en la cual el usuario ingrese 10 números y agrupándolos de a dos los sume entre sí."**

Estaba pensando en lo siguiente:

```
function sumas (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) {
var resultado0=a+b;
var resultado1=c+d;
var resultado2=e+f;
var resultado3=g+h;
var resultado4=i+j;
}
```

Es decir, tengo que lograr que el usuario ingrese 10 números (estaba pensando en que esos números se incluyan en un array) y cada dos números se sumen entre sí.

```
var numeros=[prompt("Ingrese el primer número"), prompt("Ingrese el segundo número"), 
prompt("Ingrese el tercer número"), prompt("Ingrese el cuarto número"), 
prompt("Ingrese el quinto número"),
prompt("Ingrese el sexto número"), prompt("Ingrese el séptimo número"), 
prompt("Ingrese el octavo número"),
prompt("Ingrese el noveno número"), prompt("Ingrese el décimo número")]
```

**En resumen, no sé como hacer para que se vayan sumando cada dos. ¿Alguna ayuda?**

---

Está muy buena la respuesta (y funciona) de Kleith pero no llego a entenderla o razonarla, llegué a algo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
    function suma (a,b) {
    var resultado=a+b;
    document.write(resultado + "<br>");
}
var numeros=[parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el primer número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el segundo número")), 
parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el tercer número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el cuarto número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el quinto número")),
parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el sexto número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el séptimo número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el octavo número")),
parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el noveno número")), parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el décimo número"))]

suma (numeros[0], numeros[1]);
suma (numeros[2], numeros[3]);
suma (numeros[4], numeros[5]);
suma (numeros[6], numeros[7]);
suma (numeros[8], numeros[9]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer que esos números estén dentro de un `array` para luego recorrerlo con un `for` y sumar de a pares. Por ejemplo:

```js
// array de entrada
var numeros = [
  2,3,  // 5
  4,5,  // 9
  6,7,  // 13
  8,9,  // 17
  10,11 // 21
];
var resultados = [];

// ciclo para recorrer de a pares
for (var i = 0; i < Math.round(numeros.length / 2); i++) {
  // sumo el valor 0 y 1; 1 y 2; 3 y 4; 5 y 6; ...
  resultados.push(numeros[i * 2] + numeros[i * 2 + 1]);
}

// muestro los resultados
console.log(resultados);
```

Comment: ¿Para qué sirve "Math.round"? Utilicé el código sin esa función y dio el mismo resultado...
Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Para redondear el resultado, lo puse por precaución pero podes omitirlo.

Comment: @Kleith Tendrías que utilizar `Math.floor`. Si utilizas Math.round y el array de los números tiene un valor de más (var números = [2,3,4,5,6,7, 8,9, 10,11, **21**];) el array resultados tendrá un **NaN** al final.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente fragmento te devuelve un array con las sumas, siendo arr el array con los números introducidos por el usuario.

```
const resultado =
   arr.reduce((acc, num, i, arr) =>
      i%2 && i < arr.length - 1
         ? [...acc, num + arr[i+1]]
         : acc
   , []);

console.log(resultado);
```

Puedes encontrar información de reduce aquí [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
Un saludo